# angular : How to write reuse function for select box [ngStyle]

Tags: angular

Here is my ts file

test.component.ts

```
@Input oldData;
@Input currentData;
currentDataValues = new EmpData();
oldDataValues = new EmpData();

ngOnInit() {
if(this.currentData && Object.keys(this.currentData).length !==0){
this.currentDataValues = this.currentData;
}

if(this.oldData && Object.keys(this.oldData).length !==0){
this.oldDataValues = this.oldData;
}

test.component.html:

<tr>
<td>
<select [(ngModel)]="currentDataValues.description" #description="ngModel" (ngModelChange)="onChangeActivities($event)" id="description"
[ngStyle]="{'color':currentDataValues.description === oldDataValues.description ? 'blue' :'black'}">

<option [ngValue] = ""></option>
<option *ngFor="let data of empData" [ngValue] = "data.description" [ngStyle]="{'color':'black'}">{{data.description}}</option></select>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>

<td>
<select [(ngModel)]="currentDataValues.country" #country="ngModel" (ngModelChange)="onChangeActivities($event)" id="country"
[ngStyle]="{'color':currentDataValues.country === oldDataValues.country ? 'blue' :'black'}">
<option [ngValue] = ""></option>
<option *ngFor="let data of empData" [ngValue] = "data.country" [ngStyle]="{'color':'black'}">{{data.country}}</option></select>
</td>
</tr>
```

The above code in each feild i am writting inline css:

```
[ngStyle]="{'color':currentDataValues.description === oldDataValues.description ? 'blue' black'}">
[ngStyle]="{'color':currentDataValues.country === oldDataValues.country ? 'blue' black'}">
```

instead of the above line i want to write reuse function in ts file where we can check condition assign color to selected option

kindly help